# Accessing list of list returned by itertools.product Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python Script, Looks like as below,

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
>>> b=itertools.product(*a)
>>> b
```

Now b will contain following elements ,

`[(1,4,7),(1,4,9), .......]` all combinations

How to access elements of this object returned by the itertools.product,
If you do `list(itertools.product(*a))`,  for large number of elements in `a` this gives memory error

The objective of above code is , to get such combination with maximum associate value,

This value gets computed while iterating first time , and it gets stored in scores[],
based on the the index of sum  argmax(scores),  i want to retrieve particular combination from  the object

Iterating again to such element of index i will be costly ?

Code Snippet, (exhaustive method)
[CodeLink](https://github.com/pradeephrish/nlp/blob/pradeep/hmm.py)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  While iterating, can't you save the maximal element based on whatever your criteria is?  Why do you need the index at all?  And if you *do* need the index, all you need to do is save that too.

Comment: no, because, sum for each combination can't be compared while it gets computed, therefore i need to find maximum score outside first iteration

Comment: @pradeep, usually this can be done in a single iteration. Why can't it be done in your case?

Comment: emission is one parameter used ( emission probability)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the idea behind itertools is that you *iterate* over the object returned:

```
for item in itertools.product(*a):
    do_something(item)
```

If you need to have more than one item at a time, then you need to work out how to cache those without getting a `MemoryError` yourself.

Comment: while iterating i am computing some maximum number per combination, in the end I have to get the particular combination by it's index

Comment: @pradeep -- You can use `enumerate` to get the index without materializing a list or tuple.

Comment: @pradeep, you don't need to get the index, you can just get `max` to return the item directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the item with the maximum score using a single iteration over the product like this

```
item = max(itertools.product(*a), key=score_func)
```

If you need the score *and* the item

```
score, item = max((score_func(i), i) for i in itertools.product(*a))
```

Comment: one question, how will score function receive parameters, because score function iterates over all elements in combination

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in only the item with the max value from your function, then do this:

```
max_item = None

for i in itertools.product(*a):
   if not max_item:
      # First loop
      max_item = (somefunc(i),i)
      continue

   if max_item and max_item[1] < somefunc(i):
      # This item's calulated value is the new max
      max_item = (somefunc(i),i)       

print('The maximum value is {} for the item {}'.format(*max_item))
```